# Rendering complex ListView in android

Tags: android, facebook, performance, listview, render

I am developing an android app similar to other social network app such as Facebook , Google plus. Similarly my newsfeed ListView have multiple views type and also complex. Even though i am using ViewBinder , my list view feel laggy as i add in more view types. There is a clever alternative solution [here](https://code.facebook.com/posts/879498888759525/fast-rendering-news-feed-on-android/). 
 They split each list item into multiple components such as header , content , footer and so. I planned to adapt and find it difficult to start code on my own. Is there any working code available out there similar to this technique?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a RecyclerView. It's a little more work than using a ListView but it should handle the complexity you're looking for.

http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Thanks for that i will have a look into it .